# Determining the datatype equivalence of two objects in python

Tags: python

In python, `type(x)` yields the datatype of an object `x`. If I want to ascertain if two objects are of the same type, which one is more correct:

```
type(x) is type(y)
```

or

```
type(x) == type(y)
```

Are there difference of the two? I want to be sure that the two objects have exactly identical datatype; so if `type(x)` is a subclass of `type(y)` (or vice versa), the comparison should return `False`. Thanks!

Comment: @Kasramvd That question doesn't address `type`

Comment: A little fiddling in the interpreter suggests there's not much difference with the result of `type`, and either way it produces `False` with subclasses. Try `class A(float): pass; a = A(); type(a) == type(2.0)` and you will get False. However, there could be some real edge cases here that I'm not aware of, so I'll let someone who's way more familiar with Python internals answer.

Comment: `==` checks for *equality*, while `is` checks for *identity*. For most types the two concepts are the same, as `==` will delegate to an identity check. Use `is` as that is clearer. That said, you shouldn't really compare types like this; check for functionality (ducktyping) instead.

Comment: You may want to check for *subclasses* for example; `isinstance(x, type(y))` or `isinstance(y, type(x))`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the question explicitly states that "if `type(x)` is a subclass of `type(y)` (or vice versa), the [wanted] comparison should return `False`."

Comment: @das-g: right, then `isinstance()` and `issubclass()` are right out and you are left with `type(x) is type(y)`. I still feel that that's a sign of a bad design somewhere.